# Information that is not at the correct date interval should be retrieved in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table called 'EMAIL_AUDIT' . In this table , I have Column email_sent_date.

This column contain below detail...
I want to retrive the data that is not in 5 days interval in snowflake.

03-05-2021,
08-05-2021,
13-05-2021,
18-05-2021,
23-05-2021,
28-05-2021,
01-06-2021,
06-06-2021,
04-07-2021,
09-07-2021,
14-07-2021,
19-07-2021,
24-07-2021,
29-07-2021,
01-08-2021,
06-08-2021  my data.

i want output like 01-06-2021 and 01-08-2021. Please Help me out.

Comment: Does one row contain these dates separated with commas?

Comment: No, each date in each row.

Comment: `I want to retrive the data that is not in 5 days interval in snowflake.` and `i want output like 01-06-2021 and 01-08-2021.` => Difference between 28-05 and 01-06 is 4 days, and 29-07 and 01-08 is 3 days so the proposed output does not match expected rule.

Answer (score 0):

Using QUALIFY combined with LEAD/LAG:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMAIL_AUDIT
QUALIFY EMAIL_SENT_DATE < LAG(EMAIL_SENT_DATE,1, EMAIL_SENT_DATE) 
                          OVER(ORDER BY EMAIL_SENT_DATE) + INTERVAL '5 DAYS' 
  AND EMAIL_SENT_DATE > LEAD(EMAIL_SENT_DATE,1, EMAIL_SENT_DATE) 
                        OVER(ORDER BY EMAIL_SENT_DATE) - INTERVAL '5 DAYS';
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the result should be 01-06-2021 and 04-07-2021, right?

```
SELECT email_sent_date 
FROM VALUES
('03-05-2021'), ('08-05-2021'), ('13-05-2021'), ('18-05-2021'), ('23-05-2021'), 
('01-06-2021'), ('06-06-2021'), ('04-07-2021'), ('09-07-2021'), ('14-07-2021'), 
('19-07-2021'), ('24-07-2021'), ('29-07-2021'), ('01-08-2021'), ('06-08-2021')
tmp(email_sent_date)
QUALIFY LAG(TO_DATE( email_sent_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY')) OVER (ORDER BY TO_DATE( email_sent_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY'))  
< TO_DATE( email_sent_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') - INTERVAL '5 DAYS';

+-----------------+
| EMAIL_SENT_DATE |
+-----------------+
| 01-06-2021      |
| 04-07-2021      |
+-----------------+
```